# Get SMS and NOTES from DEAD android 4.4 (Qmobile x30)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, data-recovery

## Description

I guess my android OS has crashed. It is a **Qmobile x30** with Android 4.4.

## Current Condition:

I opened Messaging app, it showed black screen for 4-5 seconds and then back to menu. I restarted it and then never able to see the Home... (I thought it as crashed). I don't know much about it.

Now it's stuck on boot logo "Noir". Touch screen isn't working and the OS is not loading.
The problem is as shown:

[image: Photo of problem]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

## What do I want?

I just want to get my all the SMS and notes from the default NOTES app.

How can I get this?

## What I've already tried

Booting to recovery mode. The recover-mode is showing big pink "Q" and text label "No Commands". There only options to Tests the device are available, nothing else.

I used ADB, It's not connecting the devices when i check with `adb devices` command. it's showing empty list.

Comment: Your device uses MTK6572 chipset which is supported by MTK Droid Tools and SP Flash Tools. You can use any of them to backup userdata partition. However, I don't know the file type of the backup so can't comment on extraction of desired data.

Comment: @Firelord. thank you, I tried a lot to recover my SMS. Now, I sent for claim because its warranty period was active. when it'll come back with new OS, i'll try to recover SMS and notes If it would possible.

Comment: Ouch. The "no commands" usually shows up if one wiped the corresponding system partition (`/system` for normal boot, `/recovery` for recovery, or `/boot` for any), which a stock recovery doesn't offer. You just wrote it "crashed": was that while applying some system update?

Comment: @Izzy. Actually it was as: I opened Messaging app, it showed black screen for 4-5 seconds and then back to menu. I restarted it and then never able to see the Home... (i thought it as crashed). I don't know much about it.